# Converting JSON list values into arrays

Tags: python

I am parsing a large amount of json files where I'm converting certain list values into arrays.

For example, for the following json this code turns the "Statement" and "Resource" into an Array.

```
print(response['PVersion']['Document'])
{
    "Version": "---",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "---",
        "Action": "---",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
}

if (type(response['PVersion']['Document']['Statement'])==list):
        pass
    else:
        response['PVersion']['Document']['Statement']=[response['PVersion']['Document']['Statement']]
for elem in response['PVersion']['Document']['Statement']:
        if(type(elem['Resource'])==list):
            pass
        else:
            elem['Resource']=[elem['Resource']]
print(response['PVersion']['Document'])

Output:
{
    "Version": "---",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "---",
        "Action": "---",
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }]
}
```

The same Python code has trouble with the following json file:

```
print(response['PVersion']['Document'])
{
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": [
                "---"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "---"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "---",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "---",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "---",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "---",
            "Action": [
                "---"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "---",
            "Action": [
                "---"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the identical code from the first example I get the following error:

```
line 59, in <module>
    if(type(elem['Resource'])==list):
KeyError: 'Resource'
```

I tried adding print(elem['Resource']) before this if statement to see which Resource it's referring to.

The output:

```
*
['*']
['*']
['*']
*
```

This points to there being a problem with the second to last "Resource", but I don't see anything different with it.

**It works on similar files where there's a combination of list and array values but not on this one for some reason.**

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: It might be a typo but the sixth Statement element in your json example does not have the `Resource` key, which might be raising the `KeyError`

Comment: Oh wow, I think that's the issue! So I guess I could add a new if statement before that one where I'd check if there's a "Resource" value in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print you're seeing is from another instance, check on your input on this part:

```
{
    "Effect": "---",
    "Action": [
        "---"
    ]
},
```

Your elem has no key "Resource". It's the 6th element of your input, which matches the fact that you have 5 lines in your output log.